# how to connect a event to a function?

Tags: pyqt

I have this small media app that holds two buttons that should start and stop music. but there is something wrong to my logic... please take a look:

```
class AppWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def mediastart():
        os.system("...")

    def mediastop():
        os.system("...")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("EasySteerQT")

        start = QtGui.QPushButton("Start", self)
        start.setGeometry(50, 50, 60, 35)

        stop = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        stop.setGeometry(100, 50, 60, 35)

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
            QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))

        self.connect(start, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
            QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("mediastart()"))

        self.connect(start, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
            self, QtCore.SLOT("mediastop()"))
```

in what way is the propper way to connect a action to a function in this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `self.mediastop`. `QtCore.SLOT('mediastop()')` refers to a (in this case non-existent) slot defined in C++. Not that that's not really necessary anyway, you can use `WidgetClass.slotName` - it just saves you a conversion.

And while we're at it, you should propably switch from [old-style signals/slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/old_style_signals_slots.html) to [new-style signals/slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). E.g. `self.clicked.connect(self.mediastop)`.

Comment: ty ty, i like the new style :)